# Automatically add files other than source files to 'Compile Sources' build phase in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, xcode5

I have a custom build rule for a file type, which I setup according to [this blog post](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/02/xcode-build-rules/). The build rule is working fine and my file is compiled.

But if I add a new file of this type to the project and I select the targets, the file is currently added to the "Copy Bundle Resources" phase. Instead, I'd like to have it added to the "Compile Sources" phase automatically (if I don't do this, the build rule won't kick in).

Is there a flag or something I can set so Xcode recognizes my files as "source files"?

Comment: have you solved it?

Comment: The problem became irrelevant to me in the mean time. But no, never found a way.